# Callout lines option is missing on QGIS 3.4.3

Tags: qgis-3, leader-line

I have seen that callouts are available starting with Qgis 3.1 but for some reason I don't have it in 3.4.

I have a work around but now I think there may be other options that aren't installed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callouts line option in labelling appear in 3.10, not 3.1.
If you can't upgrade or want to stay with 3.4 you will have to use the geometry generator in symbology to draw your line ( look here : https://gist.github.com/kgjenkins/1af82a8ffdc3c99bb886e6cd9cdc298f#file-readme-md, or search GIS SE for exact procedure)

Comment: Ha! I guess it makes me feel better, sometimes I amaze myself.  Thanks for the clarification, I'll update it.  Now, to find my car keys...